# Using submatches inside and outside of system() call

Tags: regular-expression

I have this substitution, which does not work:

```
exe 's/<<\(.*\)\%(,.*\)\?>>/<<\1,'.system('ark headings \1 | head -1').'>>'
```

What I want to do is:

- capture some expression within double angle brackets: `<<\(.*\)>>`
- paste opening double angle brackets back, followed by expression and comma: `<<\1,`
- and then paste it after filtering it through some external command: `system('foo \1 | head -1 | cut -f1')`
- follow it with the closing double angle brackets: `>>`

But I can't get the expression to work...

Answer (score 2):

The `system` function is called before the search-replace is executed. It is called to generate the command.

What you can do is:

```
s/<<\(.*\)\%(,.*\)\?>>/\='<<'.submatch(1).','.system('ark headings '.submatch(1).' | head -1').'>>'/
```

The `\=` tells Vim that the substitute string is a expression, that should be evaluated on every replace.

See `:help sub-replace-expression` and `:help submatch()`.

BTW: I'm not sure what `<<\(.*\)\%(,.*\)\?>>` should match. The `\(.*\)` will match everything until the `>>`. I guess you want `<<\([^,]*\).*>>` or `<<\([^,]*\).\{-}>>`.